# Fetching data from an API - automatic updating within react.js

Tags: javascript, json, api, reactjs

I'm currently fetching data from an API - in json format. This API is updated every hour - is there any way I can automatically update this data when the API updates? I'm currently using,

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var component = this;
    var MY_ACCESS_KEY  = "REDACTED FOR PRIVACY REASONS";
    var MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES = "USD,JPY,CAD,RUB,CNY,GBP,EUR,BTC,CHF"
      $.get("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" + MY_ACCESS_KEY + "&currencies=" + MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES + "&format=1", function(data) {
        component.setState(data)
      });
  }
```

within my react component class. This is within the extends React.Component method - if that makes a subtle difference, e.g.:

```
class TickerTrader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {...

  }
```

Comment: Sockets can be one option

Answer (score -1):

**I've updated my answer with a complete component and jsFiddle...**

https://jsfiddle.net/nxwbeb9k/5/

You can fire off the API call every hour using window.setInterval().  It would also be wise to clear the interval when the component is unmounted.

```
class TickerTrader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var MY_ACCESS_KEY = "REDACTED FOR PRIVACY REASONS";
    var MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES = "USD,JPY,CAD,RUB,CNY,GBP,EUR,BTC,CHF";

    const getQuotes = () => {
      $.get("https://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=" + MY_ACCESS_KEY + "&currencies=" + MY_CHOSEN_CURRENCIES + "&format=1", (data) => {
        this.setState(data);
      });
    };

    // Fire once, immediately
    getQuotes();

    // Fire every 'n' milliseconds (5 seconds shown here, 1 hour is 3600000 ms)
    this._interval = window.setInterval(getQuotes, 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._interval && window.clearInterval(this._interval);
  }

  render() {
    const { error, quotes } = this.state;

    let list;

    if (error) {
      list = (
        <h3>{error.info}</h3>
      );
    }

    if (quotes) {
      list = (
        <ul>
          {
            Object
              .keys(quotes)
              .map(key => <li>{key}: {quotes[key]}</li>)
          }
        </ul>
      );
    }

    if (!list) {
      list = (
        <div>"Loading..."</div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {new Date().toString()}
        {list}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TickerTrader />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time looking at this for me. However, I'm receiving a lot of NaNs rather than the actual values...? Any ideas...

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know anything about your data or API. I don't see anywhere in your sample code that would refer to numbers or NaNs. I think you'd have to post all your code, or a separate question.

Comment: Could you try seeing if it works with my access key: 4a368d8077807c97b3aff9415a4d4995

Comment: Yes it works. It looks like you should be looking for data.quotes, which is an array of numbers.  http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=4a368d8077807c97b3aff9415a4d4995&currencies=USD,JPY,CAD,RUB,CNY,GBP,EUR,BTC,CHF&format=1

Comment: Yes I am looking for quotes later on in the coding - the actual mounting isn't working from the outline you have given. Nothing is being rendered, just blank space.

Comment: Where does this._interval even come from?

Comment: Can you show me that you have managed to get this working? It seems like you haven't got it working to me and are just generalising now. I have stated that something which once rendered is no longer rendering with your solution.

Comment: Here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxwbeb9k/5/  You'll need to supply a valid key; yours has apparently gone over usage limit. I put code in there to handle error situation as well. It updates every five seconds, for demo purposes, but you can change to 3600000ms for one hour. To illustrate its working without a working API key on hand, I added a block of test data that you can render if you comment/uncomment out a line. Hope this helps you.